# update data multiple codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hello i have data array

```
function help_upd2($id)
  {
    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM outbound WHERE id_outbound_voice='$id' ")->result();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($sql as $value) {
      $data[] = $value->qty_outbound;
    }
    echo "<pre>", print_r($data);
  // $a = $data * 100000;
  // $this->db->query("UPDATE outbound SET total = '$a' WHERE id_outbound_voice = '$id'");
  }
```

$data output ->

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5 // * 100000
    [1] => 1 // * 100000
    [2] => 1 // * 100000
)
```

here I want to update the output value * 100000

Answer (score 0):

When you are fetching from db it pulls them as string so you need to cast int on them to make math operations. Do this in the loop `$data[] = (int) $value->qty_outbound * 100000;`